# Set active excecutable from iPad to iPhone

Tags: xcode

I may be too stupid to find it, but I am programming an iPhone app and everytime, when I first launch XCode in the morning, and I try to run or debug my app, the iPad-simulator starts up, instead of the iPhone one. So, is there any way to change that or do I have to live with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the iOS Simulator menu bar: Hardware -> Device -> { iPad, iPhone, iPhone (Retina) }

Comment: that the only way? no default property to set? ^^

Comment: No, it just remembers the last used setting between launches. If it's not sticking, try opening a different project and see what happens. Maybe there is something goofy in your project settings.